# iOS Simulator doesn't load iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, xcode

I've upgraded to Mountain Lion und also upgrade to the latest Version of XCode (V 4.4).

I use the iOS Simulator mainly for Webdevelopment and not for iOS Development therefore I'm not that into this matter.

When I launch the iOS Simulator it takes quite a while to load and the "beachball" is rotating. After 30sec or so the beachball is gone and the simulated iPhone is kinda ready - however, it doesn't show any OS. It's just a black screen!

If I see the iOS Version under `Hardware - Version`  there is only one available option `4.3.2 (8H7)` which is checked.

Moreover when I launch the iOS Simulator and the "beachball" appears my fans go crazy and the computer gets really hot.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Just to clarify: you have installed iOS Simulator from inside Xcode's preferences and you're starting the iOS Simulator from inside XCode, right?

Comment: no I'm launching the iOS Simulator directly not within Xcode.

Comment: However doesn't make a difference. If I launch the Simulator through Xcode the same happens - even though I have also updated to the iOS Simulator 5.0 — when launching the Simulator it still launches the 4.3 Version like @XCool says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mountain Lion seems to have dropped support for iOS Simulator 4.3. More on this if you check the official developer forums: http://devforums.apple.com

FYI, I'm  also seeing the exact same issues as yours: beach ball and loud fans. I had to kill a process called SimulatorBridge to stop the fan from spinning.

Comment: Exact same problem here. If I look in my Developers Directory under iOS Simulator and show the file-info it still says version 4.3. But I downloaded the Simulator Version 5.0 inside Xcode. http://cl.ly/image/0W3Y1I2B3v3f